# Запретить доступ и индексацю

Tags: .htaccess, apache, доступ

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть сайт, и сейчас я хочу прикрутить к нему панель управления. И вот вопрос: как лучше запретить индексацию этого раздела?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в корне сайта файл `robots.txt` и запишите в него следующее:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /имя_директории/$
```

Подробнее о `robots.txt` можно почитать [тут](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml).

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Примените мета атрибут noindex: "*Чтобы предотвратить появление страницы в результатах поиска Google, вставьте в HTML-код страницы атрибут noindex или заголовок noindex в запросе HTTP. Во время сканирования робот Googlebot обнаружит его и проигнорирует страницу, даже если на нее ссылаются другие сайты. **Внимание! Поисковый робот не обнаружит атрибут noindex, если страница заблокирована в файле robots.txt**. Такая страница может быть представлена в результатах поиска (например, если на нее есть ссылка на другой странице). Чтобы заблокировать большую часть поисковых роботов, добавьте следующий мета тег в раздел  веб-страницы: ". Статья Гугл **[Блокировка индексирования при помощи атрибута noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=ru)**.